# R [Shiny] How to implement helper functions into a dynamical model using deSolve and Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to implement a Vensim Model that I built, using R-Shiny and the deSolve Package. The model itself is inspired by a Report from Rethink X but I tried to adapt it to the swiss situation.

It basically simulates an energy grid which is solely powered by Wind, Solar, Li-Batteries, and Hydro Power.

I've had trouble getting the model running in R-Shiny as I have never used a helper function in combination with a dynamic model in R.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(deSolve)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

#TODO define vectors for the data inputs
set.seed(1)
solarData <- rnorm(FINISH, mean = 0.5,sd=1)
set.seed(1)
windData <- rnorm(FINISH, mean = 0.5,sd=1)
set.seed(1)
demandData <- rnorm(FINISH, mean = 0.5,sd=1)
set.seed(1)
hydroRunOffData <- rnorm(FINISH, mean = 0.5,sd=1)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("iSolarCap", "Solar Capacity", min = 20000, max = 150000, step = 2000, value = 50000),
  sliderInput("iWindCap", "Wind Capacity", min = 50, max = 500, step = 50, value = 50),
  sliderInput("iGrowthFactorDemand", "Growth Factor Demand", min = 1, max = 1.5, step = 0.05, value = 1),
  sliderInput("iLithiumCap", "Lithium Capacity", min = 1000, max = 100000, step = 1000, value = 10000),
  
  plotOutput(outputId = "arrange")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #defining Values that can be changed
  solarCap <- reactiveVal(1)
  windCap <- reactiveVal(1)
  growthFactorDemand <- reactiveVal(1)
  lithiumCap <- reactiveVal(1)

  #creating simulation timeline vector
  START <-1; FINISH<-17522; STEP<-1
  simtime <- seq(START, FINISH, by = STEP)
  
  #TODO define vectors for the data inputs
  solarData <- soldata
  windData <- windata
  demandData <- demdata
  hydroRunOffData <- rivdata


  
  observe({
    
    #linking input with functions ??not sure if thats what it does
    solarCap(input$iSolarCap)
    windCap(input$iWindCap)
    growthFactorDemand(input$iGrowthFactorDemand)
    lithiumCap(input$iLithiumCap)
    
    #Assigning Stocks
    stocks   <- c(sLithium = lithiumCap(),
                  sPumpedHydro =1,
                  sSuperPower=0)
    

    
    #Assigning Auxiliary variables that are constants
    auxs <- list(aSolarCap = solarCap(),
                 aWindCap  = windCap(),
                 aGrowthFactorDemand = growthFactorDemand(),
                 aEfficiencyLithium = 0.95,
                 aCLithium = 0.5,
                 aLithiumCap = lithiumCap(),
                 aEfficiencyPumpedHydro = 0.75,
                 aChargePowerPumHydro = 5000,
                 aPumpedHydroCap = 150000)
    
    #Maybe here is the spot to put the various if Then Functions ????
    chargeFunction <- function(supplydemandGap){
      if (supplydemandGap>=0){
        return(supplydemandGap)
      }
    }
    
    dischargeFunction <- function(supplydemandGap){
      if (supplydemandGap<0){
        return(supplydemandGap*-1)
      }
    }
    
    #This Function checks how much Charge Lithium should get
    currentLithiumChargePower <- function(sLithium, aCharge, aLithiumCap, aEfficiencyLithium) {
      availableCap <- (aLithiumCap-sLithium)
      potCharge    <- (aCharge/aEfficiencyLithium)
      chargePower  <- (aCLithium*aLithiumCap)/aEfficiencyLithium
      
      if (sLithium < aLithiumCap){#check if there is still capacity left
        if (availableCap<potCharge){#check if available capacity is smaller than potential charge
          if (chargePower<=potCharge){#check if charge power is smaller than potential charge
            return(chargePower) #returning charge power if pot power higher
          }
          else{#returning potential charge if charge power not achieved
            return(potCharge)
          }
        }
        else{#if potential charge is higher than available capacity
          if (chargePower<=availableCap){#check if charge power is smaller than available Capacity
            return(chargePower) #returning charge power if available Capacity higher
          }
          else{
            return(availableCap)
          }
        }
      }
      else{
        print("Lithium is Full")
      }
    }
    
    #Checks how much charge pumped hydro should get
    currentPumHydroChargePower<- function(sPumpedHydro,aCharge,aLithiumCharging,aPumpedHydroCap,aChargePowerPumHydro){
      availableCap <- (aPumpedHydroCap-sPumpedHydro)
      potCharge    <- (aCharge-aLithiumCharging)/aEfficiencyPumpedHydro
      chargePower  <- aChargePowerPumHydro/aEfficiencyPumpedHydro
      
      if (sLithium < aLithiumCap){#check if there is still capacity left
        if (availableCap<potCharge){#check if available capacity is smaller than potential charge
          if (chargePower<=potCharge){#check if charge power is smaller than potential charge
            return(chargePower) #returning charge power if pot power higher
          }
          else{#returning potential charge if charge power not achieved
            return(potCharge)
          }
        }
        else{#if potential charge is higher than available capacity
          if (chargePower<=availableCap){#check if charge power is smaller than available Capacity
            return(chargePower) #returning charge power if available Capacity higher
          }
          else{
            return(availableCap)
          }
        }
      }
      else{
        print("Pumped Hydro is Full")
      }
    }
    
    #checks how much excess power is generated 
    currentExcessPower <- function(aCharge, aLithiumCharging, aPumHydroCharging){
      excessPower <- aCharge - aLithiumCharging - aPumpHydroCharging
      if (excessPower > 0){
        return(excessPower)
      }
    }
    
    #checks how much lithium can be discharged
    curLithiumDischarge <- function(sLithium, aDischarge,aCLithium,aLithiumCap){
      availableCap <- (sLithium)
      potDischarge <- (aDischarge)
      dischargePow <- (aCLithium*aLithiumCap)
      
      if (sLithium>0){#check if there is still capacity left
        if (availableCap>potDischarge){#check if available capacity is bigger than potential discharge
          if (dischargePow<potDischarge){#check if discharge power is smaller than potential discharge
            return(dischargePow) #returning charge power if pot power higher
          }
          else{#returning potential discharge if discharge power not achieved
            return(potDischarge)
          }
        }
        else{#if potential discharge is higher than available capacity (almost empty)
          if (dischargePow<=availableCap){#check if discharge power is smaller than available Capacity
            return(dischargePow) #returning charge power if available Capacity higher
          }
          else{
            return(availableCap)
          }
        }
      }
      else{
        print("Lithium is Empty")
      }
      
    }
    
    #checks how much Pumped Hydro can be discharged
    curPumHyDischarge <- function(sPumpedHydro, aDischarge,aLithiumDischarge,aChargePowerPumHydro){
      availableCap <- (sPumpedHydro)
      potDischarge <- (aDischarge- aLithiumDischarge)
      dischargePow <- (aChargePowerPumHydro)
      
      if (sPumpedHydro>0){#check if there is still capacity left
        if (availableCap>potDischarge){#check if available capacity is bigger than potential discharge
          if (dischargePow<potDischarge){#check if discharge power is smaller than potential discharge
            return(dischargePow) #returning charge power if pot power higher
          }
          else{#returning potential discharge if discharge power not achieved
            return(potDischarge)
          }
        }
        else{#if potential discharge is higher than available capacity (almost empty)
          if (dischargePow<=availableCap){#check if discharge power is smaller than available Capacity
            return(dischargePow) #returning charge power if available Capacity higher
          }
          else{
            return(availableCap)
          }
        }
      }
      else{
        print("Pumped Hydro is Empty")
      }
    }
    
    model <- function(time,stocks,auxs){
      with(as.list(c(stocks,auxs)),{
        #Getting the current input values
        aSolarProduction <- solarData[time]*aSolarCap
        aWindProduction  <- windData[time]*aWindCap
        aHydroRunOff     <- hydroRunOffData[time]
        aDemand          <- demandData[time]*aGrowthFactorDemand

        
        
        aSupplyDemandGap <- aDemand - (aSolarProduction+aWindProduction+aHydroRunOff)
        
        #checking if grid needs charge or discharge
        aCharge          <- chargeFunction(aSupplyDemandGap)
        aDischarge       <- dischargeFunction(aSupplyDemandGap)
        
        #Finding the amount that lithium can be charged
        aLithiumCharging <- currentLithiumChargePower(sLithium,aCharge, aLithiumCap,aEfficiencyLithium)
        fChargingLithium <- aLithiumCharging*aEfficiencyLithium
        
        #Finding the amount that Pumped Hydro can be charged
        aPumHydroCharging<- currentPumHydroChargePower(sPumpedHydro,aCharge,aLithiumCharging,aPumpedHydroCap,aChargePowerPumHydro)
        fChargingPumHydro<- aPumHydroCharging*aEfficiencyPumpedHydro
        
        #Excess Power Deliverance
        fSPCharging      <- currentExcessPower(aCharge, aLithiumCharging, aPumHydroCharging)
        
        #Finding discharge of Lithium
        aLithiumDischarge<- curLithiumDischarge(sLithium, aDischarge,aCLithium,aLithiumCap)
        fDischargingLi   <- aLithiumDischarge
        
        #Finding discharge of Pumped Hydro
        aPumHydroDisch   <- curPumHyDischarge(sPumpedHydro, aDischarge, aLithiumDischarge,aChargePowerPumHydro)
        fDischargingPumHy<- aPumHydroDisch
        
        
        
        ###Stored Hydro to be implemented

        
        dL_dt            <- fChargingLithium - fDischargingLi
        dP_dt            <- fChargingPumHydro -
        #dH_dt            <- #StoredHydro
        dS_dt            <- fSPCharging
        
        return(list(c(dL_dt, dP_dt, dS_dt),
                    
                    ChargingLithium = fChargingLithium,
                    ChargingPumpedHydro = fChargingPumHydro,
                    ExcessPower = fSPCharging
                    ))
      })
    }
    

    
    o <- data.frame(ode(y=stocks, times=simtime, func = model,
                        parms = auxs, method = "euler"))
    
    
    #Basically Plotting the data
    flow_plot <- ggplot(data = o, mapping = aes(time, ChargingLithium)) + theme_classic() +
      geom_line(data = o, mapping = aes(time, ChargingLithium), size = 1, color = "blue", linetype =2)+
      geom_line(data = o, mapping = aes(time, ChargingPumpedHydro), size = 1, color = "red",linetype =2)+
      geom_line(data = o, mapping = aes(time, ExcessPower), size = 1, color = "black")
    
    f <-   renderPlot({
      flow_plot <- ggplot(data = o, mapping = aes(time, ChargingLithium)) + theme_classic() +
        geom_line(data = o, mapping = aes(time, ChargingLithium), size = 1, color = "blue", linetype =2)+
        geom_line(data = o, mapping = aes(time, ChargingPumpedHydro), size = 1, color = "red",linetype =2)+
        geom_line(data = o, mapping = aes(time, ExcessPower), size = 1, color = "black")
    })
    
    capital_plot <- ggplot(data = o, mapping = aes(time, sLithium)) + theme_classic() +
      geom_line(data = o, mapping = aes(time, sLithium), size = 1, color = "blue", linetype =2)+
      geom_line(data = o, mapping = aes(time, sPumpedHydro), size = 1, color = "black")+
      geom_line(data = o, mapping = aes(time, sSuperPower), size = 1, color = "yellow")
    
    ressource_plot <- ggplot(data = o, mapping = aes(time, sCapital)) + theme_classic() +
      geom_line(data = o, mapping = aes(time, sResource), size = 1, color = "black", linetype =1)
    
    output$arrange <- renderPlot({
      grid.arrange(flow_plot,capital_plot,ressource_plot, nrow = 3)
    })
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now the error I get is: Warning: Error in currentLithiumChargePower: object 'aCLithium' not found.

I am really not sure if I put the helper functions in the right spot or if I have to put them somewhere outside the observe function. Altough I think this is not the problem, as I tried with a print statement and the previous function chargeFunction does execute.
The problem seems to be in the assignment:

```
    currentLithiumChargePower <- function(sLithium, aCharge, aLithiumCap, aEfficiencyLithium) {
  print("I execute!!!")
  availableCap <- (aLithiumCap-sLithium)
  potCharge    <- (aCharge/aEfficiencyLithium)
  chargePower  <- (aCLithium*aLithiumCap)/aEfficiencyLithium
  print("I don't execute")
```

I have the input data in a csv, but since it doesn't really matter I just generated random vectors. If you'd like the data though I'm happy to provide it.

Thank you very much for reading and hopefully you can help me out.

Comment: Can you please simplify your code, i.e. provide a **minimal** reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

The code provided by the OP is quite long, so we don't knof if someone invests time to it. In case the "helper function" is just a function that exists outside of `server` and `ui`, it can just be implemented as "global". Here a **minimal** example taken from [here](https://tpetzoldt.github.io/deSolve-shiny/deSolve-shiny.html):

```r
library("deSolve")

brusselator <- function(t, y, p) {
  with(as.list(c(y, p)), {
    dX <- k1*A   - k2*B*X    + k3*X^2*Y - k4*X
    dY <- k2*B*X - k3*X^2*Y
    list(c(X=dX, Y=dY))
  })
}

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$brussels <- renderPlot({
    parms <- c(A=input$A, B=input$B, k1=1, k2=1, k3=1, k4=1)
    out <- ode(y = c(X=1, Y=1), times=seq(0, 100, .1), brusselator, parms)
    matplot.0D(out)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("A", label = "A", value = 1),
  numericInput("B", label = "B", value = 3),
  plotOutput("brussels")
)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Note also that an `observer` function can be avoided here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot tpetzoldt for the answer.

I could solve my issue by just passing through the variable in the function call.

```
aLithiumCharging <- currentLithiumChargePower(sLithium,aCharge, aLithiumCap,aEfficiencyLithium,aCLithium)
```

Which I figured out after reducing my problem to the minimal replicable example. I thought I tried that but apparently not.

Thanks a lot